# Directed tree mutation algorithms

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-algorithm

I came up with a problem o detecting "mutations" between two directed trees.

Example:
tree1:

```
    A         
   /  \        
  B    C - D      
 / \  / \   \ 
G   A 2  A   3
| \   |\ 
1  3  2 3
```

tree2:

```
    A         
   /  \        
  B    C - F      
 / \  /    \ 
G   A 2     3
| \   |\ 
1  3  2 3
```

The algorithm should find that there is a mutation with

```
R
|
C - D
|\   \
X Y   Z
```

Subsituted with

```
R
|
C - D
|   \
X    Z
```

Where  R, Y and Z are the respective values

I am looking for any ideas, which might be:

- link to algorithm or book with some algorithms
- pseaudocode
- code in any language (preferably python)
- library in any language (preferably Python)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at any tree difference problems?

Most tree diff problems produce a list of changes (e.g. insertion, deletion, moving, and relabelling of nodes) rather than a template subtree, but they might give you a starting place.

Comment: Thanks, can You povide some links to known solutions?